# Passing a variable value from Control Flow to Data Flow in SSIS

Tags: sql-server-2008, ssis, business-intelligence

I have a fairly straightforward SSIS package where I can't sucessfully pass the value of a package-scoped variable from the Control Flow to a Data Flow task.  Consider the below diagram:

[image: Control Flow]

The Execute SQL task gets values from a list of "machines".  This is used to control a ForEach Loop Container, which works very well.  Next a script task performs some math and assigns a single number to a package scoped variable (integer type).  I have added message boxes that pop up during the loop so that I can verify that the value of this variable is being set properly.

The last icon is a data flow where I want to use the variable value.  I have a simple script task that contains just a message box showing me the current value of this same variable.  Every time, the variable is the value that I initially set in the designer (BIDS).  Therefore, the value is not being "passed" to the data flow.  I have verified multiple times that the names of the variables are correct (including case sensitive values).

This should be pretty simple, and I am getting frustrated with this issue.  I would greatly appreciate and suggestions or comments.  Thank you!

Comment: Verify you haven't declared that same variable inside the scope of the data flow. What you are doing is a fairly standard operation

Comment: Thanks for the great suggestions.  I set a breakpoint, and it appears that the package variable is being set correctly.  I didn't see the same variable declared within the data flow.  Just to make sure, I created a brand new variable, substituted that everywhere and deleted my original variable.  When I ran it, I had the same issue.  I think I might try and create a small package just to verify this concept in a more simple manner.

Comment: Even though the asker 'feels like an idiot' at the end, this post illustrates useful trouble shooting, and the question is asked well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How are you setting the package variable from your script task?  It should look like this (c#):

```
DTS.Variables["testVariable"].Value = "some value";
```

Then to test it from the script component in your dataflow task:

```
public override void PostExecute()
{
    base.PostExecute();

    MessageBox.Show(Variables.testVariable, "test");
}
```

I did this in a test package and it worked fine.

EDIT

Also make sure that you added the variable to the ReadWriteVariables section of the properties for the script tasks.

Comment: How annoying.  After I tested that this concept does work in a small new project, I reread the area where I was setting the variable value.  I had the wrong variable name in the statement, which was causing my bug.  I feel like an idiot.  Thank everyone for helping me debug this typo, and I am sorry to take up your time.